# Calculate the sum $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_i \mod a_j $ in $\mathbb{Z}.$

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic

Calculate  the sum $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_i \mod a_j $$ for some integer $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}.$
If we calculated the usual sum $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_i a_j $$ then it would be easy since $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_i a_j=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_i \right)^2$$
and we have the complexity $O(n).$
Unfortunatelly $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_i \mod a_j \neq  \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_i \right) \mod a_j \right).$$

**Question.** Is there an algorithm better then $O(n^2)$  for calculating the sum?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_i = n \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$?

Comment: Sorry, corrected, should be  $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_i a_j$$